# Why does taking the derivative of the Lagrangian give me the method of Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: calculus, optimization

Suppose we are trying to solve the following problem:

\begin{align}
  \text{minimize} & \hspace{8pt} f(x) \\
  \text{subject to} & \hspace{8pt} g(x) = 0,
\end{align}
where $f$ and $g$ are both differentiable.

The method of Lagrange multipliers says that we should solve the following system of equations:
\begin{align}
  \nabla f(x) &= \lambda \nabla g(x) \\ 
  g(x) &= 0.
\end{align}

If I form the Lagrangian, then I get this equation:
$$L(x,\lambda) = f(x) - \lambda g(x).$$

If I take the gradient of the Lagrangian $L$ and set it equal to $0$, I find that I get the system of equations that I must solve for the method of Lagrange multipliers.  The derivative with respect to $x$ gives me the first equation, and the derivative with respect to $\lambda$ gives me the second equation.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a connection between the derivatives of the Lagrangian function and the equations in the method of Lagrange multipliers?  Definitely yes.

Comment: I think you want $L(x, \lambda) = f(x) - \lambda g(x)$ in this formulation; with $L(x, \lambda) = f(x) + \lambda g(x)$ one gets $\nabla f = -\lambda \nabla g$, which works, but is not what is stated in the problem.  Cheers!

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Excellent.  Would you explain what the connection is and why?

Comment: What is the problem here? It seems that you are fine with the statement

"The method of Lagrange multipliers says that we should solve the following system of equations:
\begin{align}
  \nabla f(x) &= \lambda \nabla g(x) \\ 
  g(x) &= 0."
\end{align}

Now this statement is **obviously equivalent** with the quoted statement about the Lagrangian $L(x,\lambda)$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter  In introductory calculus books, they develop and prove the two equations you listed.  I'd like a way to get to the equations from the Lagrangian, but I don't see an intuitive way to understand why the solution would be a saddle point of the Lagrangian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection comes from calculus.

Consider the problem:

\begin{align}
\text{minimize} \quad & f(x)  \\
x \in \quad & [a,b]
\end{align}

If the point where $f$ attains its minimum is $x^*$, then from the extreme value theorem, $$\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}(x^*) = 0$$

Now add some equality constraints to this problem to get a general constrained problem.

\begin{align}
\text{minimize} \quad & f(x)  \\
\text{subject to} \quad & g(x) = 0 \\
x \in \quad & X 
\end{align}

The method of Lagrange multipliers forms a new function called the Lagrangian: 
$$\mathcal{L}(x, \lambda) = f(x) \ +\ \lambda g(x) $$

Under some assumptions, it can be proved that if $x^*$ is the point where the equality constrained problem above is minimised, then there is a unique $\lambda^*$ such that

$$\nabla \mathcal{L}(x^*, \lambda^*) = 0$$

This along with the original equality constraint simplifies to the system of equations in your question.

Comment: Why is a critical point of $\mathcal{L}$ the solution?  Is the proof complicated?  Is there some intuitive way to understand this?

Comment: To put it very roughly, if $x^*$ is an optimal solution for $(3)$, then it is also feasible, which means that $g(x^*) =0$, i.e., the Lagrangian is just the calculus problem in disguise. Now the reason why we bother forming the Lagrangian at all is because the domain $X$ need not be as simple as in the case of the calculus problem or the constraints may be inequalities or non-linear and then, the theory of Lagrange multipliers gives us important information on the solutions.

Comment: For a proof refer to the book by [Bertsekas](https://www.amazon.com/Constrained-Optimization-Lagrange-Multiplier-computation/dp/1886529043)